# JPA Eclipse link from Open JPA - IBM WAS 8.5.12 server

Tags: jpa, db2, websphere, eclipselink

I would like to migrate to Eclipse link and JPA 2.1 on IBM WAS server and DB2. Could you please advice the sets need to be followed? If anyone used before, please explain to us what are the things to have cared? 
I am going through the document - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/can-i-use-jpa-2-1-on-websphere-application-server/

Comment: What persistence provider are you migrating from? Also, are you migrating from a previous WAS version to a newer version (for instance, traditional WAS 8.5.5 -> 9.0 or perhaps -> Liberty)?

Comment: OpenJPA to eclipse link JPA2.1 on WAS 8.5.12

Answer (score 1):

If you want JPA 2.1 I'd strongly suggest to migrate to WebSphere Liberty (preferably) , as it fully supports that and you already have license for that if you have WAS 8.5, or migrate to tWAS 9.0. On WAS 8.5.x you will have to disable JPA scanning, use application-managed persistence, create shared liberary.... not really worth.

In addition to server settings changes you will have to migrate your app from OpenJPA to EclipseLink. There is free Eclipse plugin -  [WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit) that you can configure to scan your application sources for OpenJPA -> EclipseLink migration.

But also for WAS 8.5.x -> WebSphere Liberty migration ;-)

Comment: Thanks !! unfortunately it coporate world.. you don't have a lot of control.